# c pointer to array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I know this question has been asked a lot, but I'm still unclear how to access the structs.

I want to make a global pointer to an array of structs:

```
typdef struct test
{
    int obj1;
    int obj2;
} test_t;

extern test_t array_t1[1024];
extern test_t array_t2[1024];
extern test_t array_t3[1025];

extern test_t *test_array_ptr;

int main(void)
{
    test_array_ptr = array_t1;

    test_t new_struct = {0, 0};
    (*test_array_ptr)[0] = new_struct;
}
```

But it gives me warnings. How should I access the specific structs with `[]`?

Similarly, how should I create an array of pointers of struct type? `test_t *_array_ptr[2];`?

Comment: Shouldn't give you warnings, should give an error. `(*test_array_ptr)[0]` dereferences twice, but there is only one level of stars.

Comment: @DanielFischer: gcc, for example, frequently prints warnings for constructs that are "constraint violations" (about as close as C comes to saying that something is *illegal*). The `-pedantic-errors` option makes it behave more strictly.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, but for that specific problem, gcc says `deref.c:18:18: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector` without any flags. (Hmm, what's a `vector`, this is C?) For stuff like dereferencing a struct, or accessing a member of an `int`, where the compiler just has no clue how it should do it, it gives up and throws an error.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The syntax you are looking for is somewhat cumbersome, but it looks like this:

```
// Declare test_array_ptr as pointer to array of test_t
test_t (*test_array_ptr)[];
```

You can then use it like so:

```
test_array_ptr = &array_t1;
(*test_array_ptr)[0] = new_struct;
```

To make the syntax easier to understand, you can use a `typedef`:

```
// Declare test_array as typedef of "array of test_t"
typedef test_t test_array[];
...
// Declare test_array_ptr as pointer to test_array
test_array *test_array_ptr = &array_t1;
(*test_array_ptr)[0] = new_struct;
```

The [cdecl](http://www.cdecl.org/) utility is useful for deciphering complex C declarations, especially when arrays and function pointers get involved.

Comment: thanks for the helpful answer! but what is the difference from the first answer. where function foo()
{
    test_array_ptr = array_t1;

    test_t new_struct = {0,0};
    test_array_ptr[0] = new_struct;
}

Comment: Please show how to get access to (*test_array_ptr)[1].obj1 but with -> operator. Is it possible? I understand that test_array_ptr[1]->obj1 will give me incorrect result.

Answer (score 5):

`test_t * test_array_ptr` is a pointer to `test_t`. It could be a pointer to single instance of `test_t`, but it could be a pointer to the first element of an array of instances of `test_t`:

```
test_t array1[1024];

test_t *myArray;
myArray= &array1[0];
```

this makes `myArray` point to the first element of `array1` and pointer arithmetic allows you to treat this pointer as an array as well. Now you could access 2nd element of `array1` like this: `myArray[1]`, which is equal to `*(myArray + 1)`.

But from what I understand, what you actually want to do here is to declare a pointer to pointer to `test_t` that will represent an array of pointers to arrays:

```
test_t array1[1024];
test_t array2[1024];
test_t array3[1025];

test_t **arrayPtr;
arrayPtr = malloc(3 * sizeof(test_t*));   // array of 3 pointers
arrayPtr[0] = &array1[0];
arrayPtr[1] = &array2[0];
arrayPtr[2] = &array3[0];
```

Comment: how would i just create a pointer to a single array struct at a time? and how would I access a struct within the array?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that you are taking `(*test_array_pointer)` which is the first element of the array. If you want to assign to a specific element of the array, you would do the following...

```
function foo()
{
    test_array_ptr = array_t1;

    test_t new_struct = {0,0};
    memcpy( &test_array_ptr[0], &new_struct, sizeof( struct test_t ) );
}
```

if you want to always assign to the first element of the array you could do this...

```
function foo()
{
    test_array_ptr = array_t1;

    test_t new_struct = {0,0};
    memcpy( test_array_ptr, &new_struct, sizeof( struct test_t ) );
}
```

and has been pointed out to me by others, and something I honestly had entirely forgotten for having not used it in the better part of forever, you can do direct assignment of simple structures in C...

```
function foo()
{
    test_array_ptr = array_t1;

    test_t new_struct = {0,0};
    test_array_ptr[0] = new_struct;
}
```

Comment: Im pretty sure you can copy structs ( not pointers to structs ) by using simply `=` .

Comment: Yes, you can. That's for example one way to copy arrays with a simple assignment, wrap them in a `struct`.

Comment: Yeah... that was bone headed... just something I haven't used in decades and forgot you even could. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a pointer to a pointer like:

```
test_t array_t1[1024];
test_t **ptr;
ptr = array_t1;
ptr[0] = ...;
ptr[1] = ...;
etc.
```