# C structure pointer to a structure array, from a structure - v2

Tags: c, pointers, struct

stuck, please help.
I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47758987/c-structure-pointer-to-a-structure-array-from-a-structure) but cannot fix it !! argh !
Why does a 1B (uint8_t) work, but the 4B int or uin16_t fail ?

error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')

```
uint16_t current_frameLength =0;
uint16_t plc_tx_count = 0;

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t     Nsdu[R_DEMO_APP_NSDU_BUFFER_SIZE];
    uint16_t    position;
    uint16_t    frameLength;
} ota_buff_t;

typedef struct
{
    //ota_buff_t    (*buf_ptr)[]; //pointer to array of buf_ptr
    ota_buff_t  *buf_ptr; //pointer to array of buf_ptr
    uint8_t     buf_entry;
} ota_list_t;

    ota_list_t  ota_list;
    
    ota_buff_t *rob_buf = malloc(sizeof(ota_buff_t)*5);
    ota_list.buf_ptr = rob_buf; //enter the address of the buffer to the pointer

    *(ota_list.buf_ptr[ota_list.buf_entry].Nsdu ) = 0xD0;
    *(ota_list.buf_ptr[ota_list.buf_entry].Nsdu +1) = 0xD0;
    *(ota_list.buf_ptr[ota_list.buf_entry].Nsdu +2) = plc_tx_count & 0x00FF;
    *(ota_list.buf_ptr[ota_list.buf_entry].Nsdu +3) = plc_tx_count >>8; //POST auto-increment
    *(ota_list.buf_ptr[ota_list.buf_entry].frameLength) = current_frameLength;
```

the only line that has a compile issue is the last, with assigning the contents of variable 'current_frameLength' to a defined uin16_t variable !!!

error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')

Comment: First of all, please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* build-log into your question. Secondly, add a comment on the line in the shown code where you get the error. Thirdly, what is the type of the `frameLength` member? Is it a pointer you can dereference? Is the problem because you copy-pasted a little too much?

Comment: On a different note, for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is exactly equal to `p[i]`. Please settle on using only *one* of those ways to get an element from an array. I suggest the array-index syntax. Inconsistent use of operators makes the code harder to read and understand. And using array-index syntax would also have helped you discover the copy-paste mistake you made much easier.

Comment: note, that this works: ota_list.buf_ptr[ota_list.buf_entry].frameLength = current_frameLength;    but isn't this copying the address of the variable not the value in it? i.e i need the contents of the variable 'current_frameLength', that's why i was using the unary character * since its a pointer we are assigning the value to

Comment: You dereference a pointer, to get the value that the pointer is actually pointing to. You can't dereference something which isn't a pointer. And neither `frameLength` nor `current_frameLength` are pointers. They are actual values. You don't copy addresses or locations, you copy values.

Comment: for later, `ota_list.buf_entry` is uninitialized so `ota_list.buf_ptr[ota_list.buf_entry]` invokes undefined behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Why does a 1B (uint8_t) work, but the 4B int or uin16_t fail ?*

First of all it has nothing to do with size of type.

This works :

```
    *(ota_list.buf_ptr[ota_list.buf_entry].Nsdu ) = 0xD0;
    *(ota_list.buf_ptr[ota_list.buf_entry].Nsdu +1) = 0xD0;
    ...........
    ...........
```

because `Nsdu` is an array and these statements are assigning a value a member or array `Nsdu`.

From C17 Standard [6.5.2.1 Array subscripting]:

*[emphasis added]*

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets [] is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. **The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))).** Because of the conversion rules that apply to the binary+ operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer, E1[E2] designates the E2 -th element of E1 (counting from zero).

Based on the reference, this

```
    *(ota_list.buf_ptr[ota_list.buf_entry].Nsdu ) = 0xD0;
```

is equivalent to

```
    ota_list.buf_ptr[ota_list.buf_entry].Nsdu[0] = 0xD0;
```

and this

```
    *(ota_list.buf_ptr[ota_list.buf_entry].Nsdu +1) = 0xD0;
```

is equivalent to

```
    ota_list.buf_ptr[ota_list.buf_entry].Nsdu[1] = 0xD0;
```

and so on..

Hence, those statements are simply assigning a value to the members of `Nsdu` array.

Now coming to the error that you are getting on the statement:

```
    *(ota_list.buf_ptr[ota_list.buf_entry].frameLength) = current_frameLength;
```

error:

> *error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')*

This error indicates that you are trying to dereference an `int` type.

This is an integer:

```
ota_list.buf_ptr[ota_list.buf_entry].frameLength
```

You can dereference a pointer, but you cannot dereference an integer.

Seems like, you are confused with `buf_ptr` which is a pointer pointing to `rob_buf` which is a dynamically allocated memory and, that's why, you are trying to dereferencing it. But you don't need to dereferencing it because you already accessing the memory using the `[]` operator.

The precedence of `.` (member access) and `[]` (array subscripting) operator is same, so the statement will be processed as

```
(ota_list.buf_ptr)[ota_list.buf_entry].frameLength
```

Based on C17#6.5.2.1[Array subscripting]$2, it is equivalent to

```
(*((ota_list.buf_ptr) + (ota_list.buf_entry))).frameLength = current_frameLength;
```

which is equivalent to

```
((ota_list.buf_ptr) + (ota_list.buf_entry))->frameLength = current_frameLength;
```

Hope this helps. Let me know, if you have any further questions.

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time with such a thorough answer.  much appreciated.